# How to run this command in maven in cmd in windows "cucumber -p headless @rerun.txt"

Tags: maven, cucumber, pom.xml

I would like to how to run this command using mvn commands in cmd in windows

```
cucumber -p headless @rerun.txt
```

can some help me out,

I want to run a text file, containing

```
feature1.feature
feature2.feature
```

---- using maven in cmd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing ruby and java implementations of commands. In ruby to run something like you're asking you would do the following

```
cucumber -q @text_file.txt
```

See https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/cli/run-specific-scenarios#use-@-notation-to-specify-a-file-containing-feature-file-list for info on this specific use case.

However having said all of that, you mention maven? So just clear things up first.

Comment: Sorry, I have seen that coand in some where , I thought I can use for cucumber Junit command in Maven like mvm test -DCucumber.options= "--tags @smoketest".   I want to run cucumber feature files in customised order instaed of alphabetical order. Can you people help me out. How to run feature files in customised order using Maven  Junit cucumber commands